# Vue.js how to pass props/params from parent to child component with vue-router

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vue-router

I'm working on a simple app that shows a table of Exercises in a Dashboard. From there, a user can click on an ExerciseItem and open up an Exercise component. I've got the Dashboard component working, but cannot data to pass to the child Exercise component.

Here is my Dashboard Code:

```html
<template>
     <div class="">
       <NavDash />
        <div class="container pb-5 pt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
                <h3>Dashboard</h3>
                <p class="ml-auto">{{ $store.state.user.email }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
  
      <hr>
      <AddExercise />
      <hr>
      <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <ExerciseItem
      v-for="(exercise_item, index) in this.$store.state.exercises"
      :exercise="exercise_item"
      key="index"
    />
       </tbody>
     </table>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { firebaseApp, exercisesRef, usersRef } from '../firebaseApp'
    import AddExercise from './AddExercise.vue'
    import ExerciseItem from './ExerciseItem.vue'
    import NavDash from './NavDash.vue'

    export default {
      methods: {
        signOut() {
        this.$store.dispatch('signOut')
       firebaseApp.auth().signOut()
     }
    },
    props: ['exercise'],
    components: {
       AddExercise,
        ExerciseItem,
      NavDash
    },
    mounted() {
    exercisesRef.on('value', snap => {
        let exercises = []
        snap.forEach(exercise => {
            exercises.push(exercise.val())
        })
        console.log('exercises', exercises)
        this.$store.dispatch('setExercises', exercises)
      })
     }
    }
</script>
```

And ExerciseItem.vue:

```html
<template>
     <tr>
     
    <td class="text-left">
      <h4>{{exercise.title}}</h4>
      <p>{{exercise.description}}</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      {{exercise.categories}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <button @click="removeExercise(exercise)">X</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <router-link to="/exercises/:id">LINK</router-link>
    </td>
    </tr>
</template>

<script>
     export default {
      props: ['exercise'],
    }
</script>
```

Exercise.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <NavDash />
    Exercise {{ id }}
    <h4>{{title}}</h4>
       <p>{{description}}</p>
  </div> 
</template>

<script>
    import { firebaseApp, exercisesRef, usersRef } from '../firebaseApp'
    import NavDash from './NavDash.vue'

    export default {
     props: ['id'],
     components: {
      NavDash
     }
    }
</script>
```

And the router path:

```js
    { 
        path: '/exercises/:id', 
        name: 'Exercise',
        component: Exercise,
        props: {
            default: true
        }
    }
```

Here is my Index.js inside of my Store directory:

```js
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'
    import { mutations } from './mutations'
    import * as actions from './actions'
    import * as getters from './getters'

    Vue.use(Vuex)

    const state = {
      user: {},
      exercises: {},
      articles: {}
    }

    export default new Vuex.Store({
      state,
      mutations,
      actions,
      getters
    })
```

I tried following the documentation here: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

but I can't seem to get the router-link to work properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your route, the Exercise component receives an `id` prop, not an `exercise` prop. I do not think you can pass objects in vue-router through routes, and even if you could, I think it would be a bad practice because it would have to serialize the object in the route.

The Exercise component receives an `id` prop, and should use that to lookup the exercise. Either through an ajax request, vuex, or some other source of state. Since you are using vuex, you could create a getter that returns an object where the keys are the exercise ids, and the values are the exercises. Then you could lookup the exercise in the Exercise component using the id.

Vuex getter

```
exercisesById(state) {
    var obj = {};
    state.exercises.forEach(x => {
        obj[x.id] = x;
    });
    return obj;
}
```

Exercise component

```
<script>
import { firebaseApp, exercisesRef, usersRef } from '../firebaseApp'
import NavDash from './NavDash.vue'

export default {
 props: ['id'],
 components: {
  NavDash
 },
 computed: {
     exercise() {
         return this.$store.getters.exercisesById(this.id);
     }
 },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks... where does the getter snippet go? My vuex store has an index.js file, actions.js, mutation-types.js, and mutations.js

Comment: Here is index.js: `import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { mutations } from './mutations'
import * as actions from './actions'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const state = {
 user: {},
 exercises: {}
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
 state,
  mutations,
  actions
})`

Comment: It is different for every application. The Vuex docs for getters is here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html

Comment: getters are very similar to the mutations or actions when defining them for vuex.

Comment: I think i have it set up correctly... what should my router link be? <router-link to="/exercise/:id">LINK</router-link></td> is what I want to achieve but it doesn't work...

Comment: Based on the routes you provided in your original question, it looks like it should be plural: `<router-link to="/exercises/:id">LINK</router-link>`

Comment: How doesnt it work? You need to provide more details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @kmc0590000 - Sorry for the confusion. I've updated my original post with the current code. When I navigate to "http://localhost:8080/#/exercises/:id", the error message I get now is "Property or method "title" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render". Do you think it's an issue with not passing parameters through the router-link? Or with the getter? Thanks again!

Comment: The problem is in the error message and in unrelated to the router-link. Your Exercise component has `{{title}}` in it, but that is not defined in data or as a computed. Maybe try `{{exercise.title}}`

Comment: Thanks for all of your help... that's still not working. I'm getting this error "Error in render: "TypeError: this.$store.getters.exercisesById is not a function"". Also, I've deployed the app to firebase if it helps to take a look https://tri-valley-fitnes.firebaseapp.com/#/